# multiple google maps with marker combined into slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-maps

i'm trying to make a slider which contains a google map with a marker(each slider- different city with a marker on it). I'm completely new to this. I need to use html, css and js is optional (and this is a full disaster for me)

here is a full code of my testing web page. The code for slider is fully working and also working if i'm trying to use only one map, but need 3. i quess the problem in my inability to combine and change JavaScript code in a proper way.

```js
function initMap() {
        var test= {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: test
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: test,
        map: map1
        });
    }
  
  function initMap2() {
            var test= {lat: 32.794107, lng: 34.988574};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: test
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: test,
            map: map2
            });
        }
    
    function initMap3() {
                var test= {lat: 49.2577142, lng: -123.1941149};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map3'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: test
                });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: test,
                map: map3
                });
            }
      
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
async defer
    src=
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBjCr6Pc36CWZ2t_Y7DmDk-QF2C6uUKZd8&callback=initMap"
```

```css
    .mySlides {display:none}
    #map1 {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #map2 {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #map3 {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>My Google Maps Demo</p>
<div class="w3-content">
    <div id="map1" class="mySlides"></div>
    <div id="map2" class="mySlides"></div>
    <div id="map3" class="mySlides"></div>
</div>

<div class="w3-center">
  <div class="w3-section">
    <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮ Prev</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey" onclick="plusDivs(1)">Next ❯</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Programming is not about copy/pasting functions around a file, but to keep one, and pass an argument that is than used within that function to slightly differ the execution logic. For example: `initMap(lat, lng, id)`

Comment: I know that and for now trying to figure out how the thing working out

Answer (score 0):

```js
const locations = [{
    lat: 45.840196,
    lng: 15.964331,
    name: "Zagreb",
    desc: "Lorem..."
  },
  {
    lat: 43.514851,
    lng: 16.449083,
    name: "Split",
    desc: "Ipsum..."
  },
  {
    lat: 42.645725,
    lng: 18.094058,
    name: "Dubrovnik",
    desc: "Dolor..."
  },
];

let gmap;
let slideIndex = 0; // (Indexes are 0 based, not 1!!!)
const EL_map = document.querySelector('#gmap');
const EL_desc = document.querySelector('#desc');

const ELS_slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('#slide-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('#slide-next');
const slidePrev = () => {
  slideIndex -= 1;
  showSlide();
};
const slideNext = () => {
  slideIndex += 1;
  showSlide();
};

const mapCenter = (lat, lng) => {
  const center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  gmap.setZoom(10);
  gmap.panTo(center);
};

const showSlide = () => {
  // Fix index
  if (slideIndex < 0) slideIndex = locations.length - 1;
  if (slideIndex > locations.length - 1) slideIndex = 0;
  const loc = locations[slideIndex];
  // Handle slides
  EL_desc.innerHTML = `<h2>${loc.name}</h2> ${loc.desc}`;
  // Handle gmap
  mapCenter(loc.lat, loc.lng);
};

const appInit = () => {

  // INIT GMAP
  gmap = new google.maps.Map(EL_map);
  const loc = locations[slideIndex];
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // Only one InfoWindow

  function placeMarker(loc) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng),
      map: gmap
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.close(); // Close previously opened infowindow
      infowindow.setContent(`<div id="infowindow">${loc.name}</div>`);
      infowindow.open(gmap, marker);
    });
  }
  // Pass every location to placeMarker
  locations.forEach(placeMarker);

  // INIT SLIDES
  showSlide();
  btnPrev.addEventListener("click", slidePrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener("click", slideNext);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', appInit);
```

```css
#gmap {
  height: 200px;
}

#infowindow {
  padding: 10px;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
}

.slide.is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="gmap"></div>
<button type="button" id="slide-prev">❮ Prev</button>
<button type="button" id="slide-next">Next ❯</button>
<div id="desc"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```